# Mule ESB: moving remote CSV file to another directory

Tags: ftp, mule

I am looking to use Mule to move a CSV file from one remote directory to another directory on the server for archiving. For example, move the following:
 /record/report.csv to /archive/reports/report_04_09_2015.csv. Is it possible with Mule? Just clarify an important point, the directories are not on a local server, they are on a different server. This process would require at least ftp

Comment: Yes it is possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use File inbound endpoint and configure moveToPattern and moveToDir attributes. In below example, file inbound will read a file from input folder and move it to outputDir with the name pattern specified moveToPattern. Converting file to string to make sure file is removed from input directory.

```
<flow name="MoveFile">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="input" moveToPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename + '_' + server.dateTime.format('dd_MM_yyyy')]" moveToDirectory="archiveDir" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>
        <logger message="File Moved" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

If servers are not in network, then FTP can also be used. Configure a FTP connector to set moveTo directory and pattern -

```
<ftp:connector name="FTP" pollingFrequency="1000" validateConnections="true" moveToDirectory="/archive/reports/" moveToPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename + '_' + server.dateTime.format('dd_MM_yyyy')]" doc:name="FTP"/>
<flow name="testFlow24">
        <ftp:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="21" path="/record/" connector-ref="FTP" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="report.csv"/>
        </ftp:inbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Comment: You cannot use the file connector to a remote server outside your network

Comment: That is correct, I have updated answer to show using FTP.